# Seemingly simple system of equations $x^{2} + y = 31$ and $x + y^{2} = 41$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have the following system:

$x^{2} + y = 31$

$x + y^{2} = 41$

As I try to solve it via simple substitution, I get into 4-th power equations, which I can simplify to $(x-5)(x^{3}+5x^{2}-37x-184)$ (and I am not sure how to get the cubic here). Is there a simpler way to solve this? There are 4 pairs of answers, I have got one (5 and 6).

Comment: [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) will be helpful in finding if this cubic has a rational root. Wolfram|Alpha seems to think that there are 3 real, but irrational, roots. [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3%2B5x^2%E2%88%9237x%E2%88%92184).

Comment: If you know that 6 is a root then divide x-6 into your cubic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) You'll be left with a quadratic that's easy to solve.

Comment: @user80:  $6$ is the $y$ correspoinding to $x=5$, not a separate root.

Answer (score 2):

One equation represents a parabola with a vertical axis opening downward, and the other represents a parabola with a horizontal axis opening leftward.  You can see from a sketch that there should be four intersection points.

The roots of your cubic can be solved for exactly using the cubic formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots.

It appears that your roots are not rational, nor are they square roots of rationals.  So the remaining $y$-coordinates will not be rational either.

Comment: OP will probably want to use the trigonometric form of the cubic formula, given that this is the *casus irreduciblis*.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your method seems to work great for two parabolas. The reason why is because we have [Cardano's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) to solve the cubic and [General Solutions to the Quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Quick_and_memorable_solution_from_first_principles) for cases when it does not reduce. These aren't so bad to use, right? But what's great is that this will always work for nondegenerate cases.